# In Magento 2, what does `translate="true"` really do in XML?

Tags: magento2, localisation

When I add `translate="true"` to my XML declarations of my own custom module, will Magento translate them automagically (given that I have the proper i18n CSV files for this)? Or is it only served as a flag for the `bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases`-command?

For example: I have the following XML file:

```
<type name="Example\Foo\Model\Foo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="stuff" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="hello" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Hello World!</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

And the following class:

```
namespace Example\Foo\Model;

class Foo {
    public function __construct(array $stuff = [])
    {
        var_dump($stuff);
    }
}
```

Will `$stuff['hello']` contain the translated string? Or do I still need to implement my own translation logic and is `translate="true"` merely a flag used by the `collect-phrases`-command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have proper i18n then you should set true for translate attribute in XML, (translate="true") else always set false.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. My question is: Does `translate="true"` automatically translate the string for me, or is it merely a flag used by the `collect-phrases`-scraper?

Comment: No, it will not translate automatically